# Airflow Python Unit Test?

Tags: python, airflow

I'd like to add some unit tests for our DAGs, but could not find any. Is there a framework for unit test for DAGs? There is an End-to-End testing framework that exists but I guess it's dead: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-79. Please suggest, Thanks!

Comment: I have worked on isolating all my custom logic into the `./plugins` directory and creating a test suite for the logic there. Not end-to-end but might be a good approach for you in the meantime: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/plugins.html. If you're stuffing to much untested logic into your `./dags` directory, you might want to consider breaking that out into plugins.

Answer (score 14):

Test your operators like this:

```python
class TestMyOperator(TestCase):

    def test_execute(self):
        with DAG(dag_id="foo", start_date=datetime.now()):
            task = MyOperator(task_id="foo")
        ti = TaskInstance(task=task, execution_date=datetime.now())
        result = task.execute(ti.get_template_context())
        self.assertEqual(result, "foo")
```

[Source](https://composed.blog/airflow/testing-dags)

Comment: For single task there is no dependency so it will kick off the task but it becomes complex when there is dependency. Trying for almost two days. could not get it working. It used to work in 1.7 though

Comment: @mad_ you can avoid the dependencies in your tests, see [here](https://bcb.github.io/airflow/hide-globals-in-dag-definition-file)

Comment: I want to test a dag with dependency. Avoiding depency is as good as running individual tasks

Answer (score 2):

Currently I wasn't able to find anything better than simply using `BashOperator`:

```py
with DAG('platform-test', start_date=datetime(2017, 8, 29)) as dag:
    test_command = "python3 -m unittest --verbose {}".format(platform_test_fname)
    op = BashOperator(
        task_id="platform-test",
        bash_command=test_command,
    )
```

Comment: Can you use this tactic to test the entire DAG with the goal to make the integration test?

Comment: Not quite sure @Datageek if I got your question. This was very simple usage, didn't extend that once this was set up.