# How to test airflow dag in unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, airflow

I am trying to test a dag with more than one task in the test environment. I was able to test single task associated with the dag but I want to create several tasks in dag and kick of the first task.
For testing one task in a dag I am using

> `task1.run()`

which is getting executed. But, the same is not working when I have many tasks one after another in downstream of a dag.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
# 'queue': 'bash_queue',
# 'pool': 'backfill',
# 'priority_weight': 10,
# 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args)

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='print_date',
bash_command='date',
dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
task_id='sleep',
bash_command='sleep 5',
retries=3,
dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)

t1.run() # It is executing just first task.
```

In order to run second task I have to run using t2.run() which I don't want as I am designing a DAG. How to achieve this?

Comment: I am trying to test the entire run of the dag. If we place above code inside a test statement it does not work. The bottom line is I am willing to test the entire dag run which consists of many dependent tasks using pytest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airflow Python Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418285/airflow-python-unit-test)

Comment: That link pointing to the unit test of Dag involves only one task. I want to test the entire dag rather than just one task per dag. Hope this clear out the confusion.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does the test code look like? What about `dag.run()`?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't click. simple dag.run() works. Thanks

Comment: dag.run() works in airflow 1.7 but does not seem to work in 1.9

Comment: Have a look here: https://blog.godatadriven.com/testing-and-debugging-apache-airflow

Answer (score 10):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question yet, but I'll take a stab at starting an answer.

If your goal is to just run the DAG or a subsets of its tasks manually, you can achieve this from the CLI, such as:

- `$ airflow run ...` - run a task instance
- `$ airflow test ...` - test a task instance without checking dependencies or recording state in database
- `$ airflow trigger_dag ...` - trigger a specific DAG run of a DAG

CLI docs -
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html

I think the airflow run command is the one most relevant to your use case.

At runtime, scheduling tasks in the DAGs and running downstream dependencies once their requirements are met is all handled automatically by the executor.  You shouldn't need to call run() anywhere in your code.

As far as the run method itself, the code is still there:

- DAG.run(...) - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/985a433a8d03906edfa49a99aa86c026769aff57/airflow/models.py#L4061-L4076
- TaskInstance.run(...) - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/985a433a8d03906edfa49a99aa86c026769aff57/airflow/models.py#L1711-L1722

Questions

1. When you say test a DAG "in the test environment" what do you mean exactly?  Like on the CI or in unit tests?
2. Is this code for a test or code from one of your actual DAGs?
3. Is this related to your other recent question [Test Dag run for Airflow 1.9 in unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047050/test-dag-run-for-airflow-1-9-in-unittest)?

Comment: Thanks Taylor for taking out time and providing the answer. I have to test a dag with dependencies inside the unit test. Therefore I do not wish to store on the file/ let the dag display on the GUI as it is a test dag. I want to load the entire dag within the unit test and trigger from there. It used to work in 1.7 but not really sure what I am missing to make it work in 1.9.Yes, it is related to my other question as it is related to different version so kept two questions separate to avoid confusion. The problem of running the dag as in the example above is it is not respecting the dependency