# Test Dag run for Airflow 1.9 in unittest

Tags: airflow

I had implemented test case for running an individual dag but it does not seem to work in 1.9 and may be due to stricter pool which got introduced in airflow 1.8
. 
I am trying to run below test case:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

class DAGTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def make_tasks(self):
        dag = DAG('test_dag', description='a test',
                  schedule_interval='@once',
                  start_date=datetime(2018, 6, 26),
                  catchup=False)


        du1 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy1', dag=dag)
        du2 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy2', dag=dag)
        du3 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy3', dag=dag)
        du1 >> du2 >> du3
        dag.run()

    def test_execute(self):
        self.make_tasks()
```

## exception :

```
Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: test_dag.dummy3 2018-06-26 00:00:00  [upstream_failed]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all
    upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es).
    upstream_tasks_state={'skipped': 0L, 'successes': 0L, 'failed': 0L,'upstream_failed': 1L, 'done': 1L, 'total': 1}, upstream_task_ids=['dummy2']
```

What am I doing it wrong?
I have tried both LocalExecutor and SequentialExecutor

Environment:

```
Python 2.7
Airflow 1.9
```

I believe it is trying to execute all the tasks simultaneously without respecting the dependencies. 
Note: Similar code use to work in Airflow 1.7

Comment: You didn't include enough of the actual error message: `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: test_dag. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.`

Comment: I see above exception first in stack trace and then dag_id not found exception. So wasn't sure which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with Airflow 1.7, but I guess it didn't have the same "DagBag" concept that Airflow1.8 and upwards have.

You can't run a DAG that you have created like this, because `dag.run()` starts a new python process and it will have to find the DAG from a dag folder it parses on disk - but it can't. This was included as a message in the output (but you didn't include the full error message/output)

What are you trying to test by creating a dag in the test files? Is it a custom operator? Then you would be better off testing that directly. For instance, here is how I test a custom operator stand-alone:

```
class MyPluginTest(unittest.TestCase)
    def setUp(self):
        dag = DAG(TEST_DAG_ID, schedule_interval='* * * * Thu', default_args={'start_date': DEFAULT_DATE})
        self.dag = dag
        self.op = myplugin.FindTriggerFileForExecutionPeriod(
            dag=dag,
            task_id='test',
            prefix='s3://bucket/some/prefix',
        )
        self.ti = TaskInstance(task=self.op, execution_date=DEFAULT_DATE)

        # Other S3 setup here, specific to my test


    def test_execute_no_trigger(self):
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            self.ti.run(ignore_ti_state=True)

        # It shouldn't have anything in XCom
        self.assertEqual(
            self.ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=self.op.task_id),
            None
        )
```

Comment: I have to test custom operators that have dependencies as in the example above. Are you suggesting to run the dag separately or I am missing something? Can I add the dag in DagBag somehow?

Comment: You have custom deps, or just custom operators? I would test the operator in isolation. you can't add it to the dag bag as each new process loads them fresh, so adding them to the dag bags isn't an option. If the example of testing operators I've shown can't work for you then the only other option is to have a test dag live on disk, and use that. Possibly by setting `AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER` to point to your test dir.

Comment: Above code test only one task and not entire dag. For the other approach, should I pickle the dag first to be visible and then change the Dag directory to test dir?

Comment: Thanks It took me a while to figure out how to implement. I still wonder why does Airflow does not support complete dag testing

Comment: Many operators require parameters passed at command line through conf. Those won't be available unless you are in the context of a dag run. Your example, for instance, would throw an exception if it tried to access command line parameters (or params passed through rest). How can you test such operators without running a dag, to generate a context?

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Another one mentioned [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/testing-in-airflow-part-1-dag-validation-tests-dag-definition-tests-and-unit-tests-2aa94970570c) didn`t work as no results were written to the Xcom Interface

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function you can use in a `pytest` test case that will run the tasks of your DAG in order.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pytest
from unittest import TestCase


@pytest.fixture
def test_dag(dag):
    dag._schedule_interval = timedelta(days=1)  # override cuz @once gets skipped
    done = set([])

    def run(key):
        task = dag.task_dict[key]
        for k in task._upstream_task_ids:
            run(k)
        if key not in done:
            print(f'running task {key}...')
            date = dag.default_args['start_date']
            task.run(date, date, ignore_ti_state=True)
            done.add(key)
    for k, _ in dag.task_dict.items():
        run(k)
```

You can then use test_dag(dag) instead of `dag.run()` in your test.

You'll need to make sure your logging in your custom operators uses `self.log.info()` rather than `logging.info()` or `print()`, or they won't show up.

You may also need to run your test using `python -m pytest -s test_my_dag.py`, as without the `-s` flag Airflow's stdout will not be captured.

I'm still trying to figure out how to handle inter-DAG dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Tycho for the answer. Great explanation but I need to run the dag with task dependencies in order to test the entire dag as I want to see some upstream failing and then the next tasks reporting it. I have figured out a way to keep the dag in a file and load it into dagbag during the run but still, I want to create a dag with dependencies on the fly and test the same. Will keep posting if I found any solutions. Thanks again

Comment: @mad_ you mean dependencies between tasks within a DAG? cuz that works already. The dependencies that are still WIP are the sensors.

Comment: Yeah I get your solution you are trying to individual tasks within the dag. How do you create a dag? I might give it a try. seems promising to me

Comment: any dag will do! you can either define it inline as you did in your example, or import it within your test like `from my_dag import dag` (which it'll export under even using constructs as `with DAG(...) as dag:`).

Comment: It used to work in 1.7 but will try your way of defining it and executing it. Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution. It seems it is working but without xcom which I am trying to access. SO no rows are pushed into xcom. Not sure why that is happening as those are running individually.